# Variance and standard deviation of probability distribution

Tags: probability

What is the variance of this probability distribution? Round your answer to 3 decimal places.
X   1.02    2.04    3.07    4.11
P(X)    0.24    0.25    0.28    0.23
  Could you please break down.  I also need to know how to get the standard deviation. Thank you for any help given.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the variance of a distribution?

Comment: yes and I have work it over and over.  The mean is 2.56

Comment: and then I tried to work the formula.  I do not know how to put the formula on here.  As you can tell I am new at this.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
Var(X)&=E(X^2)-E(X)^2\\
&=(1.02^2\times0.24+2.04^2\times0.25+3.07^2\times0.28+4.11^2\times0.23)-(1.02\times0.24+2.04\times0.25+3.07\times0.28+4.11\times0.23)^2\\
\end{align}$$

For part 2, look up "standard deviation" and "variance".

Comment: This is how I did it

Comment: I got ans. as 1.26 but it is wrong the book says it is 1.429.  The mean is 2.56 = 6.554 and then I got 7.814 for the second part and when I subtract I get 1.26

Comment: Slight correction